# Error while processing input value, sending via JSON

Tags: json, string, imdb

I've got following code, which should get the value of a input field, send the value to imdbapi.org and process the JSON sent back.
I included a element showing the value of the input field, but with some strings it cuts off the string. See [this test case](http://codepen.io/loredonut/pen/Izqyo)

```
$("form > input#movname").keyup(function() {
    var inputval = encodeURI($("form > input").val());
    $.getJSON('http://imdbapi.org/',
    {
        title: inputval,
        plot: "none",
        limit: "5"
    },
    function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            items.push('<li id="'+val.imdb_id+'">');
            items.push('<img src="'+encodeURI(val.poster)+'" />');
            items.push('<strong class="title">'+val.title+'</strong><br />');
            items.push('<div>'+val.rated.replace("_"," ")+'</div>');
            items.push('</li>');
        });
        items.push('<li id="debug">');
        items.push('<img src="src/nocover.png" />');
        items.push('<strong class="title">'+$("form > input").val()+'</strong><br />');
        items.push('</li>');
        var html = items.join('');
        $("#suggestions").html("");
        $('<ol/>', {
            'class': 'moviessuggestions',
            html: html
        }).appendTo('#suggestions');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `limit` is unnecessary (wrong usage?), use

```
{
    title: inputval,
    plot: "none"
}
```

and it works fine.